# 'Stuck' socket on Windows 8.1

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, windows-8.1

I recently upgraded from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1. After that upgrade, I've started having problems related to TCP sockets in Java.

An application that I work on makes use of Java `ServerSocket`s, to which another process connects to send data. Pretty standard stuff that has been working for years across many OSes and Java versions.

Under Windows 8.1, connections to these `ServerSocket`s sporadically get 'stuck'. This seems to depend somewhat on the amount of data transmitted over the socket at once, but when sending a modest ~1 kB of data at a time, it happens pretty readily.

When the socket gets 'stuck', the following happens:

- The sending side finishes sending data and closes the socket, and the process can even terminate. As far as it's concerned, the data seems to have been sent successfully.
- The receiving side generally gets some or all of the data that was sent. However, it never gets the '-1' indicator that EOF has been reached when calling `read` on the socket's `InputStream`. Instead, the process blocks indefinitely in an `InputStream.read` call.
- netstat shows that a socket connection is still ESTABLISHED to the `ServerSocket`. This is even the case if the process that sent the data has terminated (in this case `netstat -b` shows that the connection is associated with process `System`.
- I've tried connecting between systems and the problem still occurs. Specifically, I've connected from a CentOS VM (hosted by the Win 8.1 box) to the Win 8.1 box. In that case, `netstat` on the 'sending' (CentOS) machine does not continue to show an established socket, but the 'receiving' (Windows 8.1) machine does show an established socket connection.
- I've tried connecting over the loopback interface (127.0.0.1) and over the actual network interface (by specifying my externally-visible IP), with the same results.

I haven't noticed any other issues with networking since upgrading to Windows 8.1. The same code was working when running on Windows 8, so the OS upgrade seems to be the key. Specifics of my environment:

- Windows 8.1 Professional 64-bit
- Oracle HotSpot 7u40 JRE (though I've tried with 7u45 and 6u37, getting the same results)
- Dell Inspiron 5720
- Realtek PCIe FE (wired) network adapter in use

[Here is a Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7111749) of Java test programs that cause the problem in my environment. `SocketListener` must be run first. It will print a socket that it has bound to. Run `SocketTalker` with 2 parameters: the host running `SocketListener`, and the port that `SocketListener` binds to. When the problem happens, `SocketListener` reports a new socket connection and, generally, that it has received at least some of the data. However, it does not report that the socket connection was closed.

I suppose it's possible that `SocketListener` contains a bug, but it emulates the code used in a product that's worked successfully for years across many Java versions, JRE implementations, and operating systems.

Any techniques for debugging the network stack in Windows would be appreciated. I'm not much of a Windows dev...

EDIT:

[Here is a Wireshark capture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mtlr5pieo4jsibk/problem.pcapng) of a sample of the problem. 192.168.1.26 is the CentOS machine running SocketTalker, while 192.168.1.9 is the Win 8.1 machine running SocketListener. It looks like the Windows box just stops responding after the data is received. I might have stopped the capture before all was said and done, but I think I got the key portion.

Comment: Check to see if there's an updated driver for the Realtek NIC ... just a thought....

Comment: Upgraded to the latest Realtek driver, but that didn't make a difference, unfortunately. Thanks for the idea, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your server-side never closes the accepted socket. That could cause any kind of bad behaviour, certainly including the persistence of the ESTABLISHED state.

However your Wireshark trace clearly shows both an incoming FIN and an outgoing ACK so it doesn't appear to be an instance of the behaviour you describe. Note that there is no outgoing FIN from the server, which proves the point about never closing the accepted socket.

NB your description is very inaccurate. The `ServerSocket` doesn't participate in the I/O. The connection is betweeen a `Socket` at the client and an accepted `Socket` at the server.

Comment: Fair point about forgetting to close the socket - I've added that to my test program, with no change to the result. Note that the problem is frequently reproduced on the very first connection accepted by the ServerSocket, such that it never had a chance to 'not-close' the socket, as it were. SocketListener forever pends in inputStream.read, never receiving a '-1' return value.

Comment: Regarding the Wireshark trace: frame 6 appears to be an ACK to frame 4 (the PSH), not to the FIN in frame 5. This is supported by repeated retries of frame 5 in frames 7-11.